# Sort a list of arrays using the sort of other array python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, np.argsort

I have **two lists**: a list of 2D-arrays and the time it was generated, which is an integer. They are of length N and both "equally disordered". So **by using the indices to order the list *'time'* I can order the list of 2D-arrays.**

I would like to do something like:

```
ordered_list_of_arrays = np.asarray(disordered_list).argsort(np.asarray(time))
ordered_time = np.asarray(time).sort()
```

Another option would be to leave it as a list:

```
ordered_arrays = disordered_list[np.argsort(np.asarray(time))]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

By iterating np.argsort(time) I could sort my `disordered_list` but I would like to know if there is a better option for this or which are the best.

Thanks

Comment: `li.sort(key=lambda x:time_list.index(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index array and sort it based on time_list's value. Then use those indices to construct sorted versions of both arrays.

Code:

```
def sorted_lists(time_list, array_list):
    sorted_indices = sorted(range(len(time_list)), key=lambda i: time_list[i])
    sorted_time_list = [time_list[i] for i in sorted_indices]
    sorted_array_list = [array_list[i] for i in sorted_indices]
    return sorted_time_list, sorted_array_list
```